# Jquery AJAX with additional post parameters and FormData, don't call success on success

Tags: javascript, jquery

The way how I send the parameters work. The server does the right thing, and make a valid response with `application/json`.

But the success don't get called.

```js
  var fd = new FormData();
  var filelist = $('input#Image').prop('files');
  if (droppedFiles.length) {
    for (var i = 0; i < droppedFiles.length; i++) {
      fd.append('image' + i, droppedFiles[i]);
    }
  } 

  $.ajax({
    url: './doUploadDisplayImage?_id=' + id,
    type: 'POST',
    data: fd,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    cache: false,
    xhr: function () { // This is for tracking the upload status
      var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function (evt) {
        if (evt.lengthComputable) {
          doProgressBar((evt.loaded / evt.total) * 100);
        }
      }, false);
      return xhr;
    },
    success: function (res) {
      res = JSON.parse(res);
      // Don't get called
    }
  });
```

Comment: What if you make the call with postman? Can you verify that you get a 20x HTTP Code?
If you have access to the server-code that might provide more info.

Comment: add an error callback and check that hits the error callback

Comment: yes and you are really sure that backend is giving response success?

Comment: Add an `.always()` callback as well, and examine the parameters passed to it.

Comment: hold on guys working on your solution

Comment: I found the error. `res = JSON.parse(res)` is already JSON ob. I thought it wasn't, but sorry for wasting your time. Whatever, this is a good example for many beginners....